# Why I am not able to display the first 10 columns in this React Table - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am following this example of React Table from its official website - https://codesandbox.io/s/n2gqAxl7

I have a React Table which will have 13 columns, for few columns we have sub columns while for few columns we have individual columns.

My table will look like this -

[image]

As you can see the first 10 columns are independent, while the last 3 columns has child columns.

In first 10 columns the columns will have no accessor while column 6 to 10 will have the accessor of the above column (1 to 5) in one line and their own (6 to 10) accessor in a new line.

I have mainly modified the constant called columns

```
const columns = [{
  id: 'col16',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col1-heading">
          Col 1
            </div>
        <div className="col6-heading">
          Col 6
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => {
        (
          <div>
            <div className="col1">
              {d.firstName}
            </div>
            <div className="col6">
              {d.lastName}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col27',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col2-heading">
          Col 2
            </div>
        <div className="col7-heading">
          Col 7
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => {
        (
          <div>
            <div className="col2">
              {d.firstName}
            </div>
            <div className="col7">
              {d.lastName}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col38',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col3-heading">
          Col 3
            </div>
        <div className="col8-heading">
          Col 8
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => {
        (
          <div>
            <div className="col3">
              {d.firstName}
            </div>
            <div className="col8">
              {d.lastName}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col49',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col4-heading">
          Col 4
            </div>
        <div className="col9-heading">
          Col 9
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => {
        (
          <div>
            <div className="col4">
              {d.firstName}
            </div>
            <div className="col9">
              {d.lastName}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col510',
  Header: () => {
    (
      <div>
        <div className="col5-heading">
          Col 5
            </div>
        <div className="col10-heading">
          Col 10
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  accessor: (d) => {
        (
          <div>
            <div className="col5">
              {d.firstName}
            </div>
            <div className="col10">
              {d.lastName}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      },
  width: 200
},
{
  id: 'col11',
  Header: 'Col 11',
  columns: [
    {
      id: 'scol11a',
      Header: 'Sub Col 11a',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80,
    },
    {
      id: 'scol11b',
      Header: 'Sub Col 11b',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      id: 'scol11c',
      Header: 'Sub Col 11c',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      id: 'scol11d',
      Header: 'Sub Col 11d',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 'col12',
  Header: 'Col 12',
  columns: [
    {
      id: 'scol12a',
      Header: 'Sub Col 12',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 'col13',
  Header: 'Col 13',
  columns: [
    {
      id: 'scol13a',
      Header: 'Sub Col 13a',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      id: 'scol13b',
      Header: 'Sub Col 13b',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      id: 'scol13c',
      Header: 'Sub Col 13c',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    },
    {
      id: 'scol13d',
      Header: 'Sub Col 13d',
      accessor: (d) => { return (d.firstName); },
      width: 80
    }
  ]
}];
```

I have also created 2 CodeSandbox. Here is my CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/jnjrmwy3z9

https://jnjrmwy3z9.codesandbox.io/

https://codesandbox.io/s/xvr45zrnmo

https://xvr45zrnmo.codesandbox.io/

Please help to find out where I am making mistake. Why I am not able to display the first 10 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some error in your code, you did not returning the data from Header and accessor method.

please replace your index.js by this

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { makeData, Logo, Tips } from "./Utils";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

const columns = [
  {
    id: "col16",
    Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col1-heading">Col 1</div>
          <div className="col6-heading">Col 6</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    accessor: d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col1">{d.firstName}</div>
          <div className="col6">{d.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    width: 200
  },
  {
    id: "col27",
    Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col2-heading">Col 2</div>
          <div className="col7-heading">Col 7</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    accessor: d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col2">{d.firstName}</div>
          <div className="col7">{d.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    width: 200
  },
  {
    id: "col38",
    Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col3-heading">Col 3</div>
          <div className="col8-heading">Col 8</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    accessor: d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col3">{d.firstName}</div>
          <div className="col8">{d.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    width: 200
  },
  {
    id: "col49",
    Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col4-heading">Col 4</div>
          <div className="col9-heading">Col 9</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    accessor: d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col4">{d.firstName}</div>
          <div className="col9">{d.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    width: 200
  },
  {
    id: "col510",
    Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col5-heading">Col 5</div>
          <div className="col10-heading">Col 10</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    accessor: d => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col5">{d.firstName}</div>
          <div className="col10">{d.lastName}</div>
        </div>
      );
    },
    width: 200
  },
  {
    id: "col11",
    Header: "Col 11",
    columns: [
      {
        id: "scol11a",
        Header: "Sub Col 11a",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol11b",
        Header: "Sub Col 11b",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol11c",
        Header: "Sub Col 11c",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol11d",
        Header: "Sub Col 11d",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "col12",
    Header: "Col 12",
    columns: [
      {
        id: "scol12a",
        Header: "Sub Col 12",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "col13",
    Header: "Col 13",
    columns: [
      {
        id: "scol13a",
        Header: "Sub Col 13a",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol13b",
        Header: "Sub Col 13b",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol13c",
        Header: "Sub Col 13c",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      },
      {
        id: "scol13d",
        Header: "Sub Col 13d",
        accessor: d => {
          return d.firstName;
        },
        width: 80
      }
    ]
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: makeData()
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          SubComponent={row => {
            return (
              <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                <em>
                  You can put any component you want here, even another React
                  Table!
                </em>
                <br />
                <br />
                <ReactTable
                  data={data}
                  columns={columns}
                  defaultPageSize={3}
                  showPagination={false}
                  SubComponent={row => {
                    return (
                      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                        Another Sub Component!
                      </div>
                    );
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            );
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <Tips />
        <Logo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Onkar Can you please show by modifying my CodeSandbox?

Comment: Can you please tell me where was the issue?

Comment: you ahev wrote the header section like  -

Header: () => {
      (
        <div>
          <div className="col1-heading">Col 1</div>
          <div className="col6-heading">Col 6</div>
        </div>
      );
    },

You need to make it like this - 

Header: () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="col1-heading">Col 1</div>
          <div className="col6-heading">Col 6</div>
        </div>
      );
    },

"return statement was missing in your code."

Comment: I need 2 more help from you? 1st one can you please show me conditional rendering? Suppose col6 is below col1. Suppose we have two checkboxes - one for col1 and one for col6. Initially both checkboxes will be checked, if I uncheck one of the two, that header and data will become hidden. For example if I uncheck the col1 checkbox col1 data and col1 header will become hidden. Similarly if I uncheck the col6 checkbox col6 data and col6 header will become hidden.

Comment: Can you help me with conditional rendering? Suppose col6 is below col1. Suppose we have two checkboxes - one for col1 and one for col6. Initially both checkboxes will be checked, if I uncheck one of the two, that header and data will become hidden. For example if I uncheck the col1 checkbox col1 data and col1 header will become hidden. Similarly if I uncheck the col6 checkbox col6 data and col6 header will become hidden.

Comment: I have upvoted and marked your answer correct. Can youd do me a small favour? Can you help me with conditional rendering? Suppose col6 is below col1. Suppose we have two checkboxes - one for col1 and one for col6. Initially both checkboxes will be checked, if I uncheck one of the two, that header and data will become hidden. For example if I uncheck the col1 checkbox col1 data and col1 header will become hidden. Similarly if I uncheck the col6 checkbox col6 data and col6 header will become hidden.